# vsftpd cannot connect with local users

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, arch-linux

I am using arch `linux` as a `vsftpd` server can I cannot log to my **local** vsftpd server

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=NO

dirmessage_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES

ssl_enable=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem

pam_service_name=ftp

pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_min_port=6000
pasv_max_port=7000

listen=YES
```

now while I am try to login with `filezilla` to a local user that exists in the `/etc/passwd` I recv

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER test
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ***
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

and I check many times the password is correct
I have event tried to login with the root user and still same message event if I create new it does that for every user

I have followed [this doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon)

Comment: If you run `ps aux | grep vsftpd` do you see vsftpd using the correct config file?

Comment: the output is `root    687  0.0  0.2   8340  4428 ?     Ss 01:38   0:00 /usr/bin/vsftpd` but I am using the default configuration file at `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and I sure it uses it because I am using `ssl` and `filezilla` managed to connect with `ssl`

Comment: Is that your entire configuration? Do you have a line for `anonymous_enable=NO`? Try stopping the running vsftpd process, confirming you can't connect, then launching it by running the command `vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: yes I have this line (`anonymous_enable=NO`) and I have stop `vsftpd.service` and run `vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf` and im getting the same output from `filezilla` (`Response:   530 Login incorrect.`)

Comment: Can you login from the server that's running vsftpd by running `ftp localhost`?

Comment: nope still same messages while running `ftp localhost`  (after disabling the `ssl`)

Comment: Check the solution here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/413677/vsftpd-530-login-incorrect, check your pam.d rules

Comment: my users not in `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` or `/etc/ftpusers` and the users shell exists in `/etc/shells` so there is no problem with that too

Comment: Is your /etc/pam.d/vsftpd configured with a deny access list or an allow access list? If you disable the SSL options in vsftpd, does it work at all?